# HTML5 - simple pattern don't works with Smarty

Tags: regex, html, css, smarty

I'm using a simple pattern like this :

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-z]{2}" required ../>
```

But it's never valid. It seems it didn't works.

I tested it in Firefox

Is there something to active or something like that ?

My template :

```
<section class="inscription">

<h1>Inscription</h1>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="formu-inscription">

        <label for="nom"> Nom : </label> <br/><input  type="text"  id="nom" name="nom" value="{set_value('nom')}"  pattern="[a-z]{2}" required />  <br />
            {form_error('nom')} 

/* others inputs */
```

Comment: JSFiddle? What inputs aren't working? Can we have some examples?

Comment: In FF26 your pattern passes `aa` and fails `AZ` correctly. Perhaps there's something else wrong. Post your actual code.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVZXD/) works for me on Chrome 31, Mac

Comment: Your exemple works @JamesWebster, but not mines .. Don't know why

Comment: @MikeW i don't see the link at all anymore? the site was about his problem with an example page using same funtionality and different patterns.

Comment: Notably, it only validates input (for the first time) when I click submit. After that it will validate until I have valid input. Are you clicking your submit?

Comment: Yes, and it tells me an error writing "aaaa" in pattern="[a-z]{2}"

Comment: @Choubidou Your pattern validates for two-character strings. `aaaa` will fail as it's too long. Be clear what you are trying to validate here.

Comment: It's correct. `aaaa` doesn't match that pattern

Comment: Yes, but "a" or "aa" don't works too ..

Comment: Your pattern looks for exactly 2 characters. It will fail `a` as too short.

Comment: like I said, "aa" don't works too

Comment: For people using smarty template, you can do pattern="[a-z]{literal}{2}{/literal}"

Answer (score 3):

For people using smarty template, you can do

```
pattern="[a-z]{literal}{2}{/literal}"
```

Comment: Could you put the extra tags on your question so that it's more identifiable that this was a problem with Smarty.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the rendered source code you posted as a comment on a now deleted answer you have

```
 <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value="" pattern="[a-z]2" required />
```

This is not the pattern in your source that you posted in your question. It seems that you are using some unspecified templating system that is using the `{}` characters as field identifiers and is misinterpreting your pattern.

The result in your rendered page is the pattern `[a-z]2`, which will validate for a string like `a2` or `f2`, but not `a`, or `aa`, `a3` or anything longer.

Since you haven't specified what templating system you're using it's not possible to indicate how you might work around this. Possibly a pattern of `[a-z]{{2}}` might work.

Comment: Ho god.. I totally forgot the template parsing ..
Thanks you so much !
I added the good response in new answer for people